# How to convert json to csv with single header and multiple values?

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv, jsonconvert

I have input

```
data = [
  {
    "details": [
      {
        "health": "Good",
        "id": "1",
        "timestamp": 1579155574
      },
      {
        "health": "Bad",
        "id": "1",
        "timestamp": 1579155575
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "details": [
      {
        "health": "Good",
        "id": "2",
        "timestamp": 1588329978
      },
      {
        "health": "Good",
        "device_id": "2",
        "timestamp": 1588416380
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I want to convert it in csv something like below,

```
id,health
1,Good - 1579155574,Bad - 1579155575
2,Good - 1588329978,Good - 1588416380
```

Is this possible?
Currently I am converting this in simple csv, my code and response are as below,

```
f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "w", newline=""))

f.writerow(["id", "health", "timestamp"])
for data in data:
        for details in data['details']:
            f.writerow([details['id'],
                        details["health"],
                        details["timestamp"],
                        ])
```

Response:

```
id,health,timestamp
1,Good,1579155574
1,Bad,1579155575
2,Good,1579261319
2,Good,1586911295
```

So how could I get the expected output? I am using python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have done your job, I think you do not need use csv module.

And CSV does not mean anything, it just a name let people know what it is. CSV ,TXT and JSON are same things to computers, they are something to record the words.

I don't know whole patterns of your datas, but you can get output value you want.

```
output = 'id,health\n'
for data in datas:
    output += f'{data["details"][0]["id"]},'
    for d in data["details"]:
        if 'health' in d:
            output += f'{d["health"]} - {d["timestamp"]},'
        else:
            output += f'{d["battery_health"]} - {d["timestamp"]},'
    output = output[:-1] + '\n'

with open('test.csv', 'w') as op:
   op.write(output)
```